# Sort Django queryset with custom order

Tags: python, django, django-models

Let's say I have the following Django model:

```
class Todo(models.Model):
    class Priority(models.IntegerChoices):
        HIGH = 1, "High"
        LOW = 2, "Low"
        MEDIUM = 3, "Medium"

    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    priority = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=Priority.choices, db_index=True)
```

And the following test data via [factory-boy](https://github.com/FactoryBoy/factory_boy):

```
import factory
from factory.django import DjangoModelFactory

class TodoFactory(DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Todo

    title = factory.Sequence(lambda n: f"Todo {n}")

def test_custom_db_sort():
    todo1 = TodoFactory(priority=Todo.Priority.MEDIUM)
    todo2 = TodoFactory(priority=Todo.Priority.HIGH)
    todo3 = TodoFactory(priority=Todo.Priority.LOW)
    todo4 = TodoFactory(priority=Todo.Priority.MEDIUM)
    todo5 = TodoFactory(priority=Todo.Priority.HIGH)
```

I want to fetch the `Todo` objects from the database and sort from `HIGH` -> `LOW` priority. Unfortunately `Todo.Priority` isn't ordered correctly so I can't sort on that. I've come up with the following solution:

```
PREFERENCE = {
    Priority.HIGH: 1,
    Priority.MEDIUM: 2,
    Priority.LOW: 3,
}
result = sorted(
    Todo.objects.all(),
    key=lambda x: [PREFERENCE[x.priority], x.id]
)
```

This works but I'd rather sort in the database for several reasons (e.g. faster, [better to do work in the DB rather than Python](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/optimization/#do-database-work-in-the-database-rather-than-in-python)). Is there anyway to perform this query in the database?

Comment: Why don't you use HIGH=1, MEDIUM=2, LOW=3 in the `Priority` class? It would make more sense and you'd be able to sort easily.

Comment: I *could* change the integer values in the DB but it would be easier and more flexible if I didn't have to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Conditional expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/conditional-expressions/) (**`Case(...)`**, **`When(...)`**) expressions

```py
from django.db.models import Case, When, Value

new_priority = Case(
    When(priority=Todo.Priority.HIGH, then=Value(1)),
    When(priority=Todo.Priority.MEDIUM, then=Value(2)),
    When(priority=Todo.Priority.LOW, then=Value(3)),
)

qs = Todo.objects.annotate(new_priority=new_priority).order_by("new_priority")
```

---

If I have a choice, I would rather update the `Priority` choice values instead of annotating the expression.

Comment: Works great. Why would you rather update the `Priority` choice values? Is that faster?

Comment: of course not. Updating the `Priority` is more of a *logical* reason